# Apache POI HSSF: How to add shape which would not resize along with corresponding cell?

Tags: java, apache-poi, poi-hssf

I need to add shape (specifically circle) to xls-document using POI. So, I wrote following code:

```
private void drawLabel(HSSFSheet sheet, HSSFCell cell) {
    final short columnIndex = (short) cell.getColumnIndex();
    final int rowIndex = cell.getRowIndex();
    HSSFClientAnchor anchor = new HSSFClientAnchor(60, 60, 200, 200, columnIndex, rowIndex, columnIndex, rowIndex);
    anchor.setAnchorType(ClientAnchor.MOVE_DONT_RESIZE);
    HSSFSimpleShape shape = sheet.getDrawingPatriarch().createSimpleShape(anchor);
    shape.setShapeType(HSSFSimpleShape.OBJECT_TYPE_OVAL);
    ...
}
```

It works. But if I try to change column width programmatically (e.g. `sheet.setColumnWidth(0, 5 * 256);` (suppose that shape has been added to cell with column index == 0)), circle distorts and becomes like an oval (although anchor's type is set to `MOVE_DONT_RESIZE`).
What is wrong in my approach and is there a way to draw a shape which would not resize along with corresponding cell?

Answer (score 0):

I have not find proper solution of this problem. But the one way to solve problem is to scale shape (specifically its anchor) according to its actual size:

```
private void drawLabel(HSSFSheet sheet, HSSFCell cell) {
    final int defaultColumnWidth = 2048; // column width before resizing
    final int defaultRowHeight = 255; // row height before resizing
    final double xDistortionFactor = 1.0 * defaultColumnWidth / sheet.getColumnWidth(cell.getColumnIndex());
    final double yDistortionFactor = 1.0 * defaultRowHeight / cell.getRow().getHeight();

    final int dx1 = (int) (60 * xDistortionFactor);
    final int dy1 = (int) (60 * yDistortionFactor);
    final int dx2 = (int) (200 * xDistortionFactor);
    final int dy2 = (int) (200 * yDistortionFactor);
    final short columnIndex = (short) cell.getColumnIndex();
    final int rowIndex = cell.getRowIndex();
    final HSSFClientAnchor anchor = new HSSFClientAnchor(dx1, dy1, dx2, dy2, columnIndex, rowIndex, columnIndex, rowIndex);
    anchor.setAnchorType(ClientAnchor.MOVE_DONT_RESIZE);

    HSSFSimpleShape shape = sheet.getDrawingPatriarch().createSimpleShape(anchor);
    shape.setShapeType(HSSFSimpleShape.OBJECT_TYPE_OVAL);
    ...
}
```

This solution is not graceful, but it just works.

Comment: Hi, I have a somewhat similar problem (or at least the workaround looks like I should give it a try) over here I think: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28298947/npoi-images-created-in-foreach-loop-not-resizing-correctly - so I wanted to ask you if your "defaultcolumnwidth/height" is the "real" excel-defaultcolumnwidth/height? Best regards, Dominik